# Checking what execCommand using when element selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any general method to check what execCommand is using?

For example, this case: https://jsfiddle.net/7sosez5j/

Can I trigger the `execCommand` when user selected the bolded words on editor?

something like returning `bold` for me.

Sorry for my poor english. Thanks a lot